# grep find lines that contains " \t"

Tags: grep

I was requested to make a shell script to check for simple mistakes in files.
I wanted to find, for each line if

(regex:) "[ ]\t" ever happens.

The problem is that grep is ignoring the \ and is taking "t" as a literal. I also tried writting the characters themselves in a file and asking grep to read it but it didn't work.
Is there a way to find for the regex " \t" in files using any of the usual linux tools (like grep)?

I already tried:

```
grep -E --ignore-case --line-number --with-filename --file="b" file
```

(b contains: "  ")
and also:

```
grep -E --ignore-case --line-number --with-filename --regexp=" [\t]" file
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use C-style string `$'...'`

```
grep $'\t' file.txt
```

Or `sed`:

```
sed -n '/\t/p' file.txt
```

Comment: do you mean: "$ grep $' \t' file.txt" ?

Comment: That finds tabs. I need tabs after spaces.

Answer (score 7):

You can use perl regex with `--perl-regex` option like

```
 grep --perl-regex "\t"
```

Comment: it says that that option does not exist.

Comment: Works well with `GNU grep 2.11`

Comment: we are using v.2.4.2 (just checked) and I'm not allowed to update. Only the "higherups" may do something like that.