# How to match everything except a tab (for git diff --word-diff-regex)

Tags: regex, git, posix

I'm trying to do word-diff using [`git diff --word-diff-regex`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---word-diff-regexltregexgt). Basically, any matches of this regex are considered a word. My document is a tab-delimited text file, and each column may contain the whitespace character. So, I tried to use negated character class, `--word-diff-regex='[^\t]+'`, which should match everything except a tab, one or more times. However, it doesn't work. The regex seems to match everything on the line.

For example, with the text `20<\t>Hello, World` diff against `20<\t>Hello, Diff` (where `<\t>` denotes a tab character), Git should show that the difference is in the whole "Hello, {World,Diff}", not the "World" or "Diff" by itself. Using `[^\t]+`, however, causes Git to show that the entire line is a single word that changes.

Upon further research, it seems like Git internally uses POSIX's regex function. And in POSIX's infinite wisdom, it seems like I ["can’t escape anything in character classes" as "[t]hey treat backslashes in character classes as literal characters"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#special).

Inspired by [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3469155/9161044), I currently work around this by using "Negated Shorthand Character Class", `(\S| )+`. This matches anything non-whitespace, plus the whitespace character itself. This actually allows me to do word-diff in my case, but my question still remains, as this regex will not match other whitespace characters.

So, the question is, how can I match "everything except a tab" in POSIX (extended) regex (or a GNU extension), using or not using character class, without spelling all other characters in the whitespace class? For example, I don't want `(\S| |\n|\r|<other whitespace characters>)+`.

Comment: How about this - `( |[^[:blank:]])+`? Constituite `space` or any non-blank character as a word?

Comment: Hmm, as `[:blank:]` consists of only space and tab, that essentially fits my requirement. However, it still requires you to spell out the other member of `[:blank:]` out, even though there's only 1 left.

Comment: Is it as simple as escaping the backslash, as in `--word-diff-regex='[^\\t]+'` ?

Comment: @Peter, Unfortunately, no. I already used single quotes, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/skoji/6f4b91000936ffde5b077b871b272ca7

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `--word-diff-regexp` behaves a bit like `grep`, and does not undertsand escape sequences "natively".

Some ways to make it work :

- use perl regexp : `git diff` has an (undocumented ?) `-P | --perl-regexp` option :
  `git diff -P --word-diff-regex='[^\t]+'`
- tell your shell to insert a `<tab>` character :

  - (works in bash) use `$'...'` to apply ANSI-C Quoting ([bash reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)) :
    `git diff --word-diff-regex=$'[^\t]+'`
  - type `ctrl+V` followed by `<tab>` to insert a litteral `<tab>` character in your command line:
    `git diff --word-diff-regex='[^<ctrl+V <tab>>]+`
  - use `$(...)` and a command that prints a litteral `<tab>` (e.g : printf)
    `git diff --word-diff-regex="[^$(printf '\t')]+"`
  - ...

---

sources :

- [grep find lines that contains " \t"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954515/grep-find-lines-that-contains-t)
- [How to grep for tabs without using literal tabs and why does \t not work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53071/how-to-grep-for-tabs-without-using-literal-tabs-and-why-does-t-not-work) (on AskUbuntu)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking along the line of letting the shell insert the character, but I forgot how to do that. This can essentially be the accepted answer, but please edit `--word-diff-regex` to remove `p` because that's how Git's option is spelled. Also, `--perl-regexp` doesn't work.